# Nginx redirects to ```https://server_name/ ```URL instead of ```https://server_name/projectname/``` , after changing the URL from http to https

Tags: django, nginx, redirect

I have a couple of URLs like `https://server_name/projectname/`, now the problem is if I type this URL on the browser, Django (or Nginx) redirects me to `https://server_name/`, which does not exist. Actually, it should redirect me to `https://server_name/projectname/`.
Now the question is how can I say Django (or Nginx ) to do this, I don't really know if the problem is in Django or in Nginx config. I Have tried FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME= '/projectname' in settings.py but it didn't help for all urls for example `https://server_name/projectname/admin`.
By the way, it was working very well before changing the HTTP to HTTPs.

Nginx config in sites-available/project_name

```
upstream project_name_app{
  server unix:/home/webapps/project_name/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}


server {

    listen 127.0.0.1:100;
    server_name servername;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1600;

    proxy_connect_timeout       1600;
    proxy_send_timeout          1600;
    proxy_read_timeout          1600;
    send_timeout                1600;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/webapps/projectname/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/webapps/projectname/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /home/webapps/projectname/project_name/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /home/webapps/projectname/project_name/media/;
    }

    location /{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://project_name_app;
            break;

        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /home/webapps/projectname/project_name/templates/;
    }
}
```

Nginx reverse proxy config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name servername;

        # https redirect
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hammbwdsc02.emea.corp.ipgnetwork.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hammbwdsc02.emea.corp.ipgnetwork.com/privkey.pem;

        root /home/webapps/landing/landing;
        index index.html;

        # Improve HTTPS performance with session resumption
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;

        # Enable server-side protection against BEAST attacks
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384";

        # RFC-7919 recommended: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#ffdhe4096
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/ffdhe4096.pem;
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp521r1:secp384r1;

        # Aditional Security Headers
        # ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

        # ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
        # add_header X-Frame-Options DENY always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

        # ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;

        # ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection
        add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

        # Reverse Proxy
        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf;
}
```

And included proxy reverse in the last line:

```
location /projectname/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

        proxy_read_timeout 1000;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1000;
        proxy_send_timeout 1000;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:100/;
        sub_filter '="/' '="/projectname/';

        sub_filter_once off;
}
```

Main URL in Django

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('dashboards/', include('dashboards.urls')),
    path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
    re_path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
]
```

pages url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index-pages'),
    re_path(r'^login/$', views.login_page, name='login'),
    re_path(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]
```

dashboard url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
 ]
```

Comment: what is the app name?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "_how can add to my URLs the appname._" can you give an example? Please see [ask]

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the question is updated

Comment: @DavoodHadiannejad. Many possibilities here. could you share url files?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the question updated

Comment: @AtlasBravoos i did it